# Using Razor in Umbraco to display number of products

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am using Razor on Umbraco to built a cms website , I have created static pages easily 
on umbraco , I am having difficulty in creating products sections, as products section
 will be manage by the client, Product section will have sub products for instance books, accessories. 
When the user clicks on book section , all the books should be displayed vice versa. 
Can anyone help me in creating the document types and how to structure the 
content so that the client can easily add items to the products in content section.
And the system should display all the items of that product on the website.

Any example or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your document types and content nodes should be the same whether you use xslt or razor. Therefore, I recommend you take a look at

- the built-in razor macros (to see how razor is working - they're quite instructive)
- the content structure of the starter projects

The question being very broad (!), here a couple of pointers on how to go about setting up your document types and content nodes.

---

From your description, I see the following **document types**:

- *Product* : an actual product, a book, an accessory, etc..
- *ProductCategory* : a category of products, books, accessories, shoes, video games, ...
- *ProductSection* : a document type to group one or rather several ProductCategories

Of course you'll need to **add the appropriate properties to each document type** (Name, description, price, picture, etc)

Create a (first) empty **template** for each of those document types and associate them (usually done automatically when you create a new document type).

Also, you should **constrain the document types allowed as child nodes**: *Products* should not have any child nodes, *ProductCategories* should only have *Products* as child nodes, and *ProductCategories* should only be allowed to be in *ProductSections*. You may change this later on, but I think it helps to be as restrictive as possible so that the client does not insert *Product* nodes all over the place.

Head over to the content section of Umbraco and **create some nodes**: a *ProductSection* node at the root, add a child node (only *ProductCategory* should be allowed), and add some *Products*. You may add several *ProductCategories* and several *Products* for each category.

Your content tree may look something like:

- Contents

  - Products *ProductSection*

    - Books *ProductCategory*

      - ASP.NET with C# *Product*
      - C# in Depth *Product*
    - Accessories *ProductCategory*

      - Coffee mug *Product*

Every node corresponds to a web page, and the structure of these nodes will be visible in the urls.

Now start to **fill in the templates** - begin with the *ProductSection* : Loop through all child nodes of type *ProductCategory* and display a link to them - voilà the navigation through all your categories.
Continue with the template for *ProductCategory* : Display title and description/picture etc. of the current category. Then add a list of links to all child products. 
Finish with the *Product* template.

That's about it...

2 tips on properties:

- Never create a property for the order (of products within a category for example) - you should use the order of the nodes in the content tree.
- If possible, don't create properties parent-child, but again use the hierarchy of the content nodes (as described with *ProductCategory* and *Product*)